# Using Rigidbody.AddForce with a NavmeshAgent

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

Can't seem to get any of the suggestions I find to this question to work. I have an agent that follows my player, I want to push back that agent when it hits my player, and that works, but the agents position does not seem to update correctly, since after the collision it does not properly try to get to the Player again, like it thinks it's reached its position.

It also says in Unity docs that I need to set the RigidBody to Kinematic, but then I can't add force to it?

```
private void Update()
{
    if (!playerHit && followPlayer)
    {
        _agent.SetDestination(GameManager.instance.ActivePlayer.transform.position);
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (playerHit)
    {
        _rb.AddForce(-transform.forward * 10, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by disabling the navmesh agent for a certain amount of time and then re-enabling it when the velocity is near to zero.

```
private void Update()
{
    if (!playerHit && followPlayer)
    {
        _agent.SetDestination(GameManager.instance.ActivePlayer.transform.position);
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (playerHit)
    {
        agent.enabled = false; // disabling the navmesh agent.
        _rb.AddForce(-transform.forward * 10, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Implementation can be improved, let me know if it helps.

Comment: I thought of this but feels kinda ugly no?

Comment: As i've mentioned that the implementation can be improved. You'll have to work with available properties of NavmeshAgent anyway.